# Contour integral of 1/z along unit circle centred at will

Tags: complex-analysis

There is probably a duplicate, but no way to find it.

Let be $C_\alpha$ the curve along a unit circle with centre $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, $|\alpha|\ne 1$.

I expect that with $|\alpha|<1$ the integral is $2\pi i$ and for $|\alpha|>1$ the integral is zero.

Is the following computation correct? How can I derive from it the described behaviour? 
$$
\int_{C_\alpha}\frac{1}{z}\;dz
=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\alpha+e^{it}} (ie^{it})\;dt
=\left[\operatorname{Log} (\alpha+e^{it} )\right]_0^{2\pi}.
$$

$\operatorname{Log}$ in the main branch ($-\pi<\theta\le \pi$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|\alpha|<1$, then let $w=z-\alpha$.

$\displaystyle \int_{C_\alpha}\frac{dz}{z} = \displaystyle \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{i e^{i\theta} }{e^{i\theta}}d\theta = i \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta = 2 \pi i.$

If $|\alpha|>1$, then the function is holomorphic inside and on the circle.  Thus the integral is zero.  If you want, you could "compute" the antiderivative at the beginning and endpoints ($\log z_0=\log z_1$) and subtract.

Comment: I understand your answer and I +1, but my Q aims also at a comment to my  partial computation.

Comment: If $|\alpha|>1$, you can choose a branch cut away from the circle.

Comment: If $|\alpha|<1$ then yes, your calculation (almost) works.  You've specified a branch through the negative real axis.  The limits should be $\pi$ and $-\pi$.  $\textrm{Log } z=\log|z| + i\theta $ so your calculation gives $(\log \rho +i \pi )-(\log \rho -i\pi)=2\pi i$.

Comment: When $|\alpha|>1$, since you are away from the branch cut, the initial point and final point on the curve will be at the same angle, so you will have $(\log \rho + i\arg z_1) - (\log \rho + i \arg z_0)$ but here, $\arg z_1 = \arg z_0$.